# Grouping "touching" nodes of the same color together

Tags: ios, spritekit, swift

I am trying to make a very simple game that allows the user to tap on any "block" in the scene and "pop" it.  If the block is blue and touching another blue block then both blocks should be removed.

Basically I am trying to figure out how to "group" the blocks of the same color and remove them all when one of them is touched.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish this?

I tried using collision tracking to group the blocks, but that didn't seem to do the trick:

```
private func collisionBetween(box1: SKNode, box2: SKNode) {
        var blue: [SKNode] = []
        var red: [SKNode] = []
        var green: [SKNode] = []
        var yellow: [SKNode] = []
        var orange: [SKNode] = []
        
        if box1.name?.contains("blue") != nil && box2.name?.contains("blue") != nil {
            blue.append(box1)
            blue.append(box2)
            blueGroups.append(blue)
        }
        if box1.name?.contains("red") != nil && box2.name?.contains("red") != nil {
            red.append(box1)
            red.append(box2)
            redGroups.append(red)
        }
        if box1.name?.contains("green") != nil && box2.name?.contains("green") != nil {
            green.append(box1)
            green.append(box2)
            greenGroups.append(green)
        }
        if box1.name?.contains("yellow") != nil && box2.name?.contains("yellow") != nil {
            yellow.append(box1)
            yellow.append(box2)
            yellowGroups.append(yellow)
        }
        if box1.name?.contains("orange") != nil && box2.name?.contains("orange") != nil {
            orange.append(box1)
            orange.append(box2)
            orangeGroups.append(orange)
        }
    }
```

Comment: What behaviour do you observe with this code, and how does it differ from what you need? Where is this function called?

Comment: Sounds like you want a flood fill, but with blocks not pixels.... Starting from the first block, check all touching blocks and add those of the same colour to a list. Work down the list and do the same check for every block. Repeat until you hit the bottom of the list and no more blocks are added. Now you have a list of all blocks to remove

Comment: This is also called a "connected components search" and can be done with depth-first or breadth-first search algorithms. We have past Q&A with those keywords that may be useful to you.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.  I will do some more searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this is extremely simple in Swift:

```
private func getMatches(from startBlock: BlockEntity) {
    for body in startBlock.physicsBody!.allContactedBodies() {
        guard let block = body.node as? BlockEntity else { continue }
        guard block.color.accessibilityName == startBlock.color.accessibilityName else { continue }
        if !matchedBlocks.contains(block) {
            //print("MATCH!")
            matchedBlocks.insert(block)
            getMatches(from: block)
        }
    }
}
```

The important portion here is the ".allContactedBodies()".  That is a built in function for detecting any touching "nodes".